# Аннотация типов в аргументах функции python3 приводит к циклическому импорту

Tags: python, python-3.x, импорт, аннотации

Имеется модуль А, в котором есть класс

```
from b import Base

class Player(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def get_action(self):
        base.get_action()
```

Имеется модуль B, который на вход получает класс A

```
class Base(object):
    @staticmethod
    get_action():
        ....
    @staticmethod
    process_player(a: Player):  <- из за аннотации типов, требуется в данный модуль импортировать класс Player
        ....
```

Как избавиться от циклического импорта в данном случае, и не избыточна ли данная проверка типа?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Передайте аннотацию строкой:

```py
class Base(object):
    def process_player(a: 'Player'):
        pass
```

Answer (score 2):

По [PEP 563](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/) [начиная с Python 3.7](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/#enabling-the-future-behavior-in-python-3-7) можно включить отложенное ("ленивое") выполнение аннотаций с помощью импорта `from __future__ import annotations`. Например, такой код запустится без ошибок:

```
from __future__ import annotations


class Base(object):
    @staticmethod
    def get_action():
        pass
    
    @staticmethod
    def process_player(a: Player):
        pass
```

По сути в свойстве `__annotations__` для аргумента в этом случае храниться не сам класс Player, а его имя в виде строки:

```
print(Base.process_player.__annotations__)
```

выведет `{'a': 'Player'}`

[Начиная с Python 3.11](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/82786) планируется сделать это стандартным поведением.